# multiple eclipse error when starting eclipse, opening project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

yesterday i just tried to run my application on real mobile device, and it did. just that the application itself have coding error. but then when i open my other project, start eclipse today, there are manny errors. i forgot exactly which error appear when.

`.java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`,No repository found at file, , Plug-in `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ToolsLocator`. An error occurred while automatically activating bundle `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2), :/C:/Users/My%20Name/Downloads/.` right now all my import the "android" becomes cannot be resolved. along with all my other **object** can't work. `like LocationManager, button, onClickListener,String..com.google.android.gms.maps, setContentView, Bundle...and more..`

i do not know what cause these error, my eclipse seems to be missing some files. i never download anything extra on eclipse before. i tried updating but it has nothing to update. should i uninstall and reinstall eclipse? i prefer to avoid that to save me working all over again but it seem there are no other choices? i uses eclipse for a long time that nothing like that happened before..

Comment: the same thing happened with me .. i updated the Project Build Target from the properties ... worked for me

Comment: my project build target was still checked. i just check again and apply. and project clean. all errors solved. hope it won't appear again. than you so much!.  don't really understand why it appear in the first place..

Comment: try to add the libraries again after removing them and clean- build it.

Comment: happened with me when i imported the project from another system to mine .